# Links between class rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm new to rails and in my project I have 2 classes who have a relationship betwen them. The problem is they dont can list services with organs. The following is the code I have:

```
modelos

class Admin::Organ
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Search
  include Mongoid::Pagination

  field :name, type: String
  field :address, type: String
  field :acronym, type: String
  field :phones, type: String
  field :emails, type: String
  field :image, type: String
  field :permalink, type: String
  field :schedules, type: Array
  field :coordinates, type: Hash

  has_many :services, class_name: "Service"
  has_many :units, class_name: "Admin::Unit"

  before_save :touch_permalink

  search_in :name

  paginates_per 10

  def url
    "/orgao/#{permalink}"
  end

  private
    def touch_permalink
      self.permalink = self.name.parameterize
    end
end



class Service
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Search
    include Mongoid::Pagination

    field :name, type: String
    field :acronym, type: String
    field :popular_names, type: Array
    field :description, type: String
    field :free, type: Boolean
    field :applicants, type: Array
    field :estimated_time, type: Hash
    field :steps, type: Array
    field :permalink, type: String
    field :other_informations, type: String

    belongs_to :organ, class_name: "Admin::Organ"
    has_and_belongs_to_many :units, class_name: "Admin::Unit"
    has_and_belongs_to_many :audiences, class_name: "Admin::Audience"
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, class_name: "Admin::Category"

    before_save :touch_permalink

    search_in :name, :popular_names

    paginates_per 10

    def organ_id 
      read_attribute(:organ_id).to_s
    end

    def url
        "/servico/#{permalink}"
    end

    private
      def touch_permalink
        self.permalink = self.name.parameterize
      end
end


#controlers
class   ServicesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @organs = Admin::Organ.all
        @services =  Service.page(params[:page].to_i).per(3)
    end

    def show
        @service = Service.where(permalink: params[:permalink]).first

    end
end


class   OrgansController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @organs = Admin::Organ.page(params[:page]).per(2)       
    end

    def show
        @organ = Admin::Organ.where(permalink: params[:permalink]).first
        @organs = Admin::Organ.page(params[:page]).per(1)
    end
end

#call in index.html 
<%= organs.services.name%>
```

This appears to be returning an error whenever I run it

Comment: Please show the stacktrace.

Comment: Could you please add any information about the specific error you are getting with this approach

Comment: <%= organs.services.name%> this return the name "Service"! i want who return the service's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: On mongo relationships when you call a relationship method (such as services in your case) all of the documents associated with it are returned. Also for the pagination plugin you are using (I'm assuming kaminari by the syntax), this will return a collection of documents as well.

If so, it could be expected that you have a view for organs that has something a little like this:

```
<% @organs.each do |organ| %>
   <div>Name: <%= organ.name %></div>
   <div>Address: <%= organ.address %></div>
   <div>Services:</div>
   <% organ.services.each do |service| %>
       <div>Name: <%= service.name %></div>
       <div>Acronym: <%= service.acronym %></div>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= paginate @organs %>
```

You'll notice that to print out the services you need to first have a handle on the current document within @organs, and then you need to iterate the services within it. If you were to call name (which is a method of a relationship) you will get the relationship name (I believe this is what you are seeing).

I hope this helps. I had to do some guessing between the lines, come back to me if you need any further help.